# How can I create laravel blade template programmatically?

Tags: laravel-5

How can I create laravel blade template programmatically, also need to include master page to it, need to save as new blade template inside views folder?

Answer (score 1):

1. Create a view which contains the content of common blade format
2. on appropriate action, when you need to create a new blade, take the content of the common blade from step 1 using `render()` function
3. Then simply use `File` facade to actually generate the blade using the content. Something like:

   ```
   use Illuminate\Support\Facades\File;

   //in your controller method
   $file = 'path to your views folder, where you want to generate the blade';
   File::put($file, 'content from step 2');
   ```

That's all I can provide based upon the short question without any details, you have asked.

*I hope it helps*

Comment: Can you please explain in detail

Comment: Can you ask a particular question, what is not clear?

Comment: My purpose is like wordpress add new page,When admin create content using form need to create as new blade template with  route